# SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure WKWebkit iOS 10

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, ios10, wkwebview

- I am loading a web page in `UIWebView` on `iOS 10.x Simulator` which is working great.
- Now i am trying to loading same web page in `WKWebView` like this -

  ```
  @interface ViewController2 ()
  @property(strong,nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *productURL;
  @end        
  @implementation ViewController2            
      - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
          [super viewDidLoad];
          self.productURL = @"http://192.168.1.157/rockwellApp_v2/?city=719";
          NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.productURL];
          NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

          _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
          [_webView loadRequest:request];
          _webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
          [self.view addSubview:_webView];
      }
  @end
  ```

but failed to load complete web page.
When i am debugging the WKWebView in [WebKit Nightly](https://webkit.org/downloads/),It gives me  error in console like `SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure.`

**Update 1**
Error screenshot -[image]

Answer (score 1):

Calling `window.history.pushState()` with invalid or insecure parameters will trigger the exception: `SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure.`

A script in the page you loaded is most likely trying to push some history that uses a hardcoded domain or scheme (ex. `http://example.com`) which does not match with your current domain `http://192.168.1.157`.

An uncaught exception will prevent the rest of the script to evaluate. Thats why it does not load/render fully.

To debug this issue, add exception breakpoints in the web inspector and refresh the page by pressing `cmd` + `r` with the web debugger as the selected window.